# How to import excel file without superscripts using PHPEXCEL library

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am using PHPEXCEL library to import data in array, though the data is importing correctly but the superscripts in the excel file I m getting as a plain text, so

> **how can I remove these superscripts either before uploading the excel file**
>     **or after in the array**

below is the example string, and last character T is a superscript.

> Agriculture, Forestry, Fishing and HuntingT

Comment: If you don't mind can you tell, are you getting each row end of the string as a superscript character?

Comment: No they are several rows,

Comment: fyi: PHPExcel is deprecated